# Lock Background Image Size

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to figure out how to lock the size of a div's background image. I want to be able to magnify the size of the page while keeping the background image the same size, only changing the crop factor. Trying to do something similar to this... http://developers.kippt.com/

```
.div{
    background-image: url(../img/background-image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
//this will scale the background image as large as possible to cover the whole div
background-size:cover;

//for fixed positioning
background-attachment:fixed;
//to make it center (or center top, depends on your need)
background-position:center center;
```

for further information about background size, you can read the article [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [these techniques](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) before and they both work well. If you read the pros/cons of each you can decide which is right for your site.

Alternatively you could use the [full size background image jQuery plugin](http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/) if you want to get away from the bugs in the above.

Comment: don't just add links, describe the actual techniques, and add links as an extra. If the sites you link to ever change, your answer becomes useless...